# Where can I find an English dub of Naruto Shippuden episodes 78-140?

Tags: naruto

So I just got into Naruto a few months ago and have been binge-watching my way through the entire series. I watch some subbed anime but after watching so many episodes dubbed I just can't get used to subbed episodes. I've gotten to episode 77 and suddenly the dubbing is gone. The dub doesn't start again until episode 140 on Hulu, and I can't seem to find it anywhere online. Did they just never dub those episodes or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

On the Anime and Manga Meta we have a list of [Legal Streaming Sites](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/923/1587). i don't stream myself so i wouldn't know if the episodes are on there. do be aware that some sites do employ Geoblocking which, depending on where you live, you may be redirected to a local site or prevented from using it all together (as with some Youtube Chanels)

If the Episodes you are looking to Stream are not there the other alternative and legal path is to buy the DVDs. Dubbed wise Collections 6-11 have Episodes 66-140. this [RightStuf Search Result](http://www.rightstufanime.com/category/DVD?keywords=Naruto%20Shippuden) [has](http://www.rightstufanime.com/Naruto-Shippuden-DVD-Set-6-Hyb-Uncut) [these](http://www.rightstufanime.com/Naruto-Shippuden-DVD-Set-7-Hyb-Uncut) [Collections](http://www.rightstufanime.com/Naruto-Shippuden-DVD-Set-8-Hyb-Uncut) [available](http://www.rightstufanime.com/Naruto-Shippuden-DVD-Set-9-Hyb-Uncut) [to](http://www.rightstufanime.com/Naruto-Shippuden-DVD-Set-10-Hyb-Uncut) [buy](http://www.rightstufanime.com/Naruto-Shippuden-DVD-Set-11-Hyb-Uncut), they ship internationally but the DVDs are Region 1, which is fine if you are in the US or have the equipment/programs to use Region 1 DVDs (ie. a Region Free Player).

if you are in Australia then [Madman](https://www.madman.com.au/series/view/15388/naruto-shippuden) list some of these collections but not all of them (no idea why they just stop after Collection 8)