# What platforms have all of naruto dubbed

Tags: naruto

I see that people are saying that all of naruto have been dubbed but on which platform because on Hulu it’s only season 3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find an English dub of Naruto Shippuden episodes 78-140?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/30097/where-can-i-find-an-english-dub-of-naruto-shippuden-episodes-78-140)

Comment: Related for Hulu: [Why did they stop giving dubbed Shippūden episodes on Hulu?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/43397/2516)

Comment: Also, take note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so we will only mention legal/official sites if they exist. Answers/comments that mention questionable sites will be removed without prompt.